# React Native Navigation Styling Issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native Navigation top tabs. I am having a issue with the text getting cut or wrap. Is there any way that I can style where all the tab names show correctly without  text wrap

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set a width to the tabbar, like this

```
tabBarOptions: {
tabStyle: {
    width: 'auto' //or put some other width which works for you
}}
```

Also consider using scrollable tabs or reducing font size.